# CSS file is not linking

Tags: php, cakephp

After loading web page my CSS file is not linking.. I have kept CSS file in **app/view/layout/css** and also in **app/webroot/css/** my controller is in **app/controller/DashboardsController.php** and my view is **app/view/Dashboards/index.ctp**. And router is linking like   **Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index', 'home'));**.

Website is running in subdomain...line .. **subdomain.maindomain.com**
I am new in cakephp can you plz tell me why CSS file is not linking...

Answer (score 1):

Generally you put your css etc. in the webroot folder:

```
app/webroot
```

So say for example the path was

```
app/webroot/css/myfile.css
```

Then when you include the files it would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/myfile.css">
```

Or use CakePHP shorthand

```
echo $this->Html->css('myfile');
```

If this isn't working then I'd check your .htaccess. Try in your browser to access the file directly: subdomain.maindomain.com/css/myfile.css . If this fails I'd say its the .htaccess.

Comment: In output source it is showing <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css" /> but when I am clicking on HREF getting this "<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /css/bootstrap.css was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at subdomain.maindomain.com Port 80</address>"

Comment: File is not opening directly from browser also..I haven't edited anything in .htaccess can you please say what I need to write there?

Comment: Hey if you follow this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

The CakePHP Docs are brilliant, hope it helps :)

Comment: I am able to access my css file by following link ...  http://sub.main.com/app/webroot/css/